# Recursion explanation with two return statements

Tags: java, recursion, return

Hey guys needed help with this recursion function, what would be the result of `g(2)`, `g(0)` and `g(-5)` in this function.

```
public static int g(int v) {
    if (v>5) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (v<=0) {
      return Math.abs(v)+g(v+2);
    }
    return (v-1)+g(v+1);
```

I get the general gist of recursion and i know `g(2)` yields `10` but i was lucky due to that number the pathway never used the first return statement. I am unsure how the `g(0)` and `g(-5)` would work... as that first return statement is evoked. could someone please explain?

Comment: Try *debugging* it using a debugger. Write all the steps on a piece of paper and then try to find out the *why*

Comment: follow the [paper stack recursion model](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+pile+paper) and actually do this yourself with paper and pencil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by writing down expressions on a piece of paper and keep expanding it and see what you get.

For `g(0)`, the second if statement is run:

```
|0| + g(2)
```

And for `g(2)` we already know it's 10, so `g(0)` is 10 as well.

For `g(-5)`, the second if statement is run:

```
|-5| + g(-3)
```

Then 2nd if statement is run again:

```
5 + |-3| + g(-1)
```

And again:

```
8 + |-1| + g(1)
```

Now, the last return statement is run:

```
9 + (1 - 1) + g(2)
```

`g(2)` is known to be 10, so

```
9 + 10 = 19
```

Answer (score 0):

- g(2) returns 10
- g(0) returns 10 as well (second if statment gets executed that returns 10

  > Math.abs(0) + g(0+2) = 10)
- g(-3)

  > Math(-3) + g(-1) = 14
- g(-1)

  > Math(-1) + g(1) = 11
- g(-5) returns 19 (second if statement gets executed that  returns 19

  > Math.abs(-5) + g(-3)) = 19